# Azure Devops Publish Artifact generates .cs,.bat etc (not deployable files) in Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to Publish my project in Azure DevOps after Build. I have provided a file share directory for the project to be published. When I publish the project, It still generates .cs, .bat files in the file share directory. I want it to generate only deployable files that get generated when we publish a project in Visual studio. Do I need to provide any arguments in the Build or Publish the task in my Build pipeline?
Please help me in understanding whats the difference between Azure DevOps Publish and Visual studio Publish of a Project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you only want the zip file and nothing more in the file share?

Comment: zip file is getting generated in the file share , but in the zip file .CS, .bat etc files (which are not deployable) are getting generated as well.

Comment: The Build task already create the deployable zip file for you, so you don't need to zip it yourself. You can update your copy file task to copy only zip (ie Contents = **/*.zip), then remove the archive task and leave the publish task as is.

Comment: No.I think you didn't get my problem. Azure DevOps build is generating class files in the file share location instead of only deployable files like dlls.Do I need to handle it in Build task or Publish task?

Comment: From what I see, the publish task only publish the zip file to the file share. Do you mean the files inside the zip are not the right one?

Comment: yes. The files inside zip consists of both deployable files and class (.cs , .bat) files which should not get generated. If we publish a project in visual studio, it doesn't generate class files in the folder. Do I need to provide any Arguments in build task or Publish task in the Build pipeline to achieve this?

Comment: Then it's because you copy every files to the intermediate folder where you do the archive task. Try selecting only the extension you want in the copy task (the `Contents` field)

Comment: What does publish do then? Does it just copy the files from Archive to my file share location? I'm trying to understand the difference between Azure Devops publish task and the Visual studio publish task. In visual studio publish you dont need to select any extensions right? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, publish basically does that. It also create an artifact for the pipeline, that you will see on the pipeline run and can for example use as a trigger for another pipeline. It has nothing to do with Visual Studio publish,

Comment: So Basically, Azure build pipeline copies files from TFS and Publishes(Copies) them to an Artifact in the file share location we provided. It has nothing to do with Visual studio build or generating only deployable files? Thanks for your answer in Advance

Comment: Exactly, it's a generic task that you can also use to publish for example javascript code or website configuration or whatever you want. It's "publishing" in the context of azure devops, not related to any program or language like Visual Studio or C#.